# UINavigationBar titleView taller than the bar itself

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

So I'm trying to do a center button on a UINavigationBar similar to the popular UITabBar customization. But its got a small problem.

Basically everything is working well, I've got the bar adjusting is size, showing the titleView properly, working with AutoLayout (topLayoutGuide). Even the push animation is working well. But the pop animation is failing. It is screenshotting or clipping to bounds and I can't find a good work around that doesn't make me just want to make a custom control and skip UINavigationBar.

Heres a video showing exactly whats going on. http://tinypic.com/r/2vl8yl1/8

Heres some code for the custom navigationBar:

```
private let NavigationBarOffset: CGFloat = 10.0

class ActionNavigationBar: UINavigationBar {

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)

        self.clipsToBounds = false
        self.contentMode = .Redraw

        // Slide the original navigationBar up to make room for the actionbutton
        transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0.0, -NavigationBarOffset)
    }

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }

    override func sizeThatFits(size: CGSize) -> CGSize {
        var expectedSize = super.sizeThatFits(size)

        // Adjust the height of the navigation bar
        expectedSize.height += NavigationBarOffset

        return expectedSize
    }
}
```

Here is the code getting the button up there:

```
navigationItem.title = "Browse"
navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItem.Bookmarks, target: nil, action: nil)
navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItem.Search, target: self, action: "next")

let button = UIButton()
button.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)
button.setTitle("+", forState: .Normal)
button.setTitle("", forState: .Highlighted)
button.titleLabel?.font = UIFont.boldSystemFontOfSize(40.0)
button.backgroundColor = self.view.tintColor
button.layer.cornerRadius = 27.0

let buttonWrapper = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 60.0, height: 60.0));
buttonWrapper.addSubview(button)

NSLayoutConstraint(item: button, attribute: .CenterX, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: buttonWrapper, attribute: .CenterX, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0.0).active = true
NSLayoutConstraint(item: button, attribute: .Bottom, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: buttonWrapper, attribute: .Bottom, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0.0).active = true
NSLayoutConstraint(item: button, attribute: .Height, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .NotAnAttribute, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 54.0).active = true
NSLayoutConstraint(item: button, attribute: .Width, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .NotAnAttribute, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 54.0).active = true

navigationItem.titleView = buttonWrapper;
```

Comment: I used a different approach to make this with with the `TabBar` Instead of trying to place the button inside the controller, I placed it over it by using the `viewWillLayoutSubviews` method. From their, you can add the button as a subview of the view `[self.view addSubview:centerTabButton];`

Comment: So in that case you'd have me subclass UINavigationController? The reason I shy'd away from that was I'd have to mimic push/pop animations with the view somehow.

Comment: Yes, you would need to subclass. True, you would also need to work out the animation. In our case, this was the only reliable way to get it to work for the `TabBar` but we didn't have to deal with animation for that.

Answer (score 2):

I have tried following in `override func viewDidLoad()`. It's working fine for me without using custom navigation bar.

```
override func viewDidLoad()
{
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    //self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdge.None
    //navigationItem.title = "Browse"

    navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItem.Bookmarks, target: nil, action: nil)
    navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItem.Search, target: self, action: "next")



    let button = UIButton()
    //button.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)
    button.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 40, 40)
    button.setTitle("+", forState: .Normal)
    button.setTitle("", forState: .Highlighted)
    button.titleLabel?.font = UIFont.boldSystemFontOfSize(40.0)
    button.backgroundColor = self.view.tintColor
    button.layer.cornerRadius = 20

    let buttonWrapper = UIView(frame: CGRect(￼ 0, y: 0, width: 40, height: 40));
    //buttonWrapper.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
    buttonWrapper.addSubview(button)

    /*NSLayoutConstraint(item: button, attribute: .CenterX, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: buttonWrapper, attribute: .CenterX, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0.0).active = true
    NSLayoutConstraint(item: button, attribute: .Bottom, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: buttonWrapper, attribute: .Bottom, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0.0).active = true
    NSLayoutConstraint(item: button, attribute: .Height, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .NotAnAttribute, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 54.0).active = true
    NSLayoutConstraint(item: button, attribute: .Width, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .NotAnAttribute, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 54.0).active = true*/

    navigationItem.titleView = buttonWrapper;
}
```

[image: iPhone 6 image]

Comment: Your view doesn't match what is shown in the video. You havne't drawn the button outside of the UINavigationBar at all.

Answer (score 1):

Generally *UINavigationBar* hight is 65. And it takes around 10 yOffset before Title for *StatusBar*. So U can set your title within 10 to to 65 yOffset of NavigationBar. The maximum height of your Button is (65-10)=55.

So u have two solutions :

1. You can change the height and width of your Button like,

   `let buttonWrapper = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 45.0, height: 45.0));`
2. Or u can change the yOffset value of Button like,

   `let buttonWrapper = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: -8, width: 60.0, height: 60.0));`